# how to use the google translator in my android application?

Tags: android, internationalization, google-translate, machine-translation

I am trying to develop an android application where I need the implementation of multiple languages within the app based on the user requirement. I googled for it and I found this link.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

In this link it takes us to the https://cloud.google.com/

I followed the instructions but finally it asked me to find the registered apps(which I don't have).
And I am stuck here. Please help me.

Comment: Check out my answer it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Android itself provides functionality to support for localisation using the strings resources.

Have you refer to the Developer Guide for [Multiple Language Support in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) ?

Check for [Localisation and language support](http://developer.vodafone.com/how-support-multiple-languages-android/)

Comment: @GrlsHu Hi thank you for your reply. Your answer is really helpful. If I want to convert into the languages like hindi(national language of India), or any other languages of eastern countries, I don't think it will work.

Comment: Yes, It will only work for the languages which are supported by android OS .